# Upload process blocks other requests AFNetworking 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3

I am trying to upload data with AFNetworking and its successful. no problem with that but the problem is when I am doing it in background than the other requests blocks and doesn't give any response until upload progress finishes.

What I did is I made a singleton and declare AFURLSessionManager in that because I want all current running task.

```
+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    static SharedManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
    @synchronized(self) {
    if (sharedMyManager == nil)
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    }

    return sharedMyManager;
}
```

Let me tell you simple example.. for one controller, I made a request for upload process like below

**ViewController1.m**

```
-(void)postImage{
    @try {
        NSMutableDictionary *otherParameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:_currentPlaceParameters];
        [otherParameters setObject:[UtitlityManager getUserID] forKey:@"user_id"];

        AFHTTPRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request =
        [serializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:URL_UPLOAD_PHOTO_VIDEO parameters:otherParameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
            NSData *thumbImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(dataValue, 0.5);
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:thumbImageData name:@"thumbnail" fileName:@"image.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
        } error:nil];

        //show progress bar on window

        AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[SharedManager sharedInstance]manager];
        manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
        NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
        uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
            // This is not called back on the main queue.
            // You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates
            float uploadActualPercentage = uploadProgress.fractionCompleted * 100;
            NSLog(@"Multipartdata upload in progress: %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f %%",uploadActualPercentage]);
        }
                                          completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                              if (error) {
                                              } else {
                                                  NSDictionary *result=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
                                                  if([[result objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue]==1){

                                                  }else{
                                                      [Common showMessageWithMessage:@"Failed, Try again"];
                                                  }

                                              }
                                          }];        
        [uploadTask resume];
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"EXC: %@",[exception description]);
    }
}
```

And than I try to move another view controller and send a request for get other data ...

**ViewController2.m**

```
-(void)getData{
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager POST:url parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSDictionary* responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {

    }];
 }
```

But this doesn't give response until progress finishes... why so??

Even I try to set this upload process in dispatch_sync but it won't work ... any suggestion on this???

Comment: I don't see any reason why your `POST` would wait for the upload to finish. But you're not showing the code where you call these two routines, so it's hard to say. I'd suggest creating [simple example that reproduces the problem in question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Until we can reproduce the problem, it's hard to fix it. Personally, I'm suspecting the problem is unrelated to the code in the question. Likely we're blocking the main thread somewhere or calling the second routine in the completion handler of the first request.

Comment: I'm not suggesting "more" code, but rather a simpler, reproducible example of the problem because AFNetworking requests run concurrently, so there's got to be something unrelated going on and we don't really want to pour through tons of code.

Comment: A couple of unrelated observations: 1. When you use `dispatch_once` pattern, no `@synchronized(self)` is needed. 2. Did you intend to use different session managers for your two requests? 3. Yes, using `dispatch_sync` in conjunction with asynchronous AFNetworking requests will never achieve the desired behavior. Frankly, you should avoid synchronous calls, anyway.

Comment: @Rob for a second point I would say I want single session manager for upload task .. .so I can get all process in any controller with this manager..

Comment: @Rob you can check that how I done that .. like in viewcontroller1, I made a request of upload process ... than in other viewcontroller made a simple post request to get data .. but won't get data until upload finishes .. thanks by the way for your support

Comment: I see nothing here that would make one wait for the other. How do you transition from one to the other? Are you doing this programmatically? If so, show us where you do that.